# Как на Python сделать так, что бы при вводе определенного слова, например выдавало одну из шести цитат?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Я хочу написать программу на Python, что бы при вводе слова `Motivation`, программа выдавала `1` из `6` заготовленных цитат и показывала пользователю,но не знаю как это сделать.

Помогите, покажите как оно работает и как это можно сделать?

Comment: Цитаты заносите в список. Когда получаете ключевое слово с помощью библиотеки random генерируете случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 6 и берете из списка элемент с эти индексом

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Через random.randint(1,6) и условие if

```
import random
if text == "Motivation":
   f = random.randint(1,6) #не помню включительно или нет 1 и 6
   if f == 1:
      print("Цитата 1")
   elif f == 2:
      print("Цитата 2")
   elif f == 3:
      print("Цитата 3")
   elif f == 4:
      print("Цитата 4")
   elif f == 5:
      print("Цитата 5")
   else:
      print("Цитата 6")
```

## если не так, то попробуй заменить == на =

Comment: Попробуй вместо использования одной связки if-elif-else использовать 2 связки while if

Comment: Экспериментируй. В консоли IDLE например

Comment: Простите, а что произойдет, если  "заменить == на =" ???  И главное - а зачем???

Comment: Да ничего особенного, только вот == является оператором сравнения (скорее всего именно == это должно быть, поскольку там "если значение_1 == значению_2, то..."), а = является оператором присваивания, просто в одном из случаев будет выдавать ошибку. Проверено

Comment: Ну да, это всем известный факт.  И проверять не надо. Вопрос был: зачем менять правильный оператор на ошибочный? Цель? Кстати, в вашем ответе - если вариантов отклика системы будет 127 будете 127 раз писать elif ? На самом деле правильный скрипт приведен в ответе ниже.

Comment: У меня память немного барахлит. Иногда забываю сколько = должно использоваться в том или ином случае.

Comment: А вам известен хоть один (действующий на сегодня) язык программирования, в которых в такой конструкции должен быть один знак равенства? Ошибится так можно и легко. А вот "забыть"???

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107732/discussion-between-slayer-leon-and-passant).

Comment: Неинтересно  и бессмысленно.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
words = list(map(str, range(6)))
while True:
    x = input('ввод')
    if x == 'Motivation':
        print(random.choice(words))
    elif x.strip():
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

articles = ['цитата 1', 'цитата 2', 'цитата 3', 'цитата 4', 'цитата 5', 'цитата 6']

word = input('Введите слово Motivation: ')
if word == 'Motivation':
    print(articles[random.randint(1, len(articles)]) 
else:
    print('Не то слово')
```